# Where can you fined Application.Current.Dispatcher?

Tags: c#, .net

This is very hard to find using Google. What Library is Application.Current.Dispatcher can be found? I cannot find it on my ClassLibrary project or cannot able to import its library.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
    DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new Action(() => { 
       this.progressBar.Value = 50;
   }));
```

Comment: `Application.Current` is in `System.Windows`.

Answer (score 2):

It's in the `System.Windows.Threading` namespace which is in the `WindowsBase.dll`

Basically `Application.Current` returns an `Application` object which interits from `DispatcherObject` and has a `Dispatcher` property.

**Application Class**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application(v=vs.110).aspx

**DispatcherObject.Dispatcher Property**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just had the same issue and I also had to add the `PresentationFramework` library to the C# project references, hope this help somebody in the future